# Randomly placing items in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, minesweeper

I'm a beginner at using Python and I've been trying to code a Minesweeper game. Basically, I'm a bit lost on how to set up my class so that it creates a 5x5 grid of cells using a list of lists, then randomly places 3 mines on this grid, and counts the number of mines in each cell's neighborhood.

I figured I would use an `__init__` method that would call on two other methods: one for placing the mines, and another for counting each cell's neighborhood.

I'm a bit lost on how to set those up though so any suggestions?

Comment: welcome to SO. To optimize your answers, please be more specific in your questions. Show some code and refer your question to it

Comment: I'd recommend [numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/) for this purpose.  It has a lot of convenient functions for 2D arrays (like a Minefield).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: I beg to differ. For a trivial list of lists, I wouldn't pull a `numpy` dependency to this project.

Comment: Fair point @EliBendersky.  It could be done either way with about the same difficulty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a little code to get you started:

```
>>> import random
>>> cells = [['empty'] * 5 for i in range(5)]
>>> for i in range(3):
        x = random.randrange(5)
        y = random.randrange(5)
        cells[x][y] = 'mine'


>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(cells)
[['empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
 ['mine', 'empty', 'mine', 'empty', 'empty'],
 ['empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'mine'],
 ['empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
 ['empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty']]
```

Comment: +1. Deleting my own answer as this one is way better. No harm in giving newbies a friendly push ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Each cell is just a coordinate (x, y) in your 2d list. So you just need to come up with three random coordinates and assign them to board[x][y] if I understand you correctly.

I might do it like this.

```
x = range(5)
y = range(5)

coord1_x = x.pop(randrange(5))
coord1_y = y.pop(randrange(5))

coord2_x = x.pop(randrange(4))
coord2_y = y.pop(randrange(4))

coord3_x = x.pop(randrange(3))
coord2_y = y.pop(randrange(4))
```

If you want more mines you can just generalize those lines of code into a loop and put the coordinates into a list. There might be a more concise way to do this though.

Don't know of an easy way to count the neighbor cells off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

To create a random list, the best is to do this -

```
import random

x = range(10)
random.shuffle(x)
```

This randomly shuffles your list in-place.

Or if you want to get an element from a list randomly, try -

```
random.choice(x)
```